# Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise или Windows Server 2008 Web?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server

Подскажите, пожалуйста! Какую из двух ОС выбрать для установки `SQL Server 2012`?

Для удаленного подключения к базам данных через `Visual Studio`.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Server 2008 R2 новее, редакция Enterprise богата по функциональности.Windows Server 2008 старее (была выпущена одновременно с Vista), редакция Web содержит самые базовые компоненты и имеет серьёзные ограничения по размеру ОП и количеству ЦП.

SQL Server 2012 будет работать на обоих системах. R2 - более современный и мощный вариант, я бы поставил его, если есть такая возможность.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще не советую `Windows 8` ставить, она ещё новая и не все в ней ошибки найдены и устранены. Поставь 7 и всё нормально будет.

Comment: А ьыор написано про 8ку?

Answer (score 0):

У меня в Голландии 2008R2 Standard Edition отлично пашет, полгода уже. Не жалуюсь! 1С SQL там прижился вполне, а чего ещё нужно? Админю, конечно, через RDP. А в конторе у меня, так вообще 2003-й, и ничего, работает! Тут дело далеко не в ОС!